# Handling UnicodeDecodeError when reading a file in Python

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I'm working on a Python project where I need to read data from a file. However, I'm running into issues with UnicodeDecodeError. I've looked into similar questions on Stack Overflow, but I couldn't find a solution that fits my case. Here are the details:

I have a file (data.txt) with some text data, and I'm using the following code to read it:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:
    content = file.read()
    # Further processing of the content
```

But when I run this code, I get the following error:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 1234: invalid start byte`

I understand that this error is related to decoding issues, but I'm not sure how to handle it properly. The file may contain characters from different encodings, and I want to ensure that my code is robust enough to handle them.

What's causing this UnicodeDecodeError, and how can I handle it correctly?
Are there any best practices for dealing with decoding issues when reading files in Python?
Is there a way to detect the encoding of the file dynamically to ensure a more robust solution?
Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I've tried specifying a different encoding when opening the file, like 'latin-1' or 'ISO-8859-1', but I still encounter decoding errors. I'm not sure how to handle this situation gracefully, considering the variability in the file's content.

Comment: To read a text file correctly you need to know what encoding it is in. Can you open it in your favorite text editor and check a.) what encoding that editor chose/guessed and b.) what's at or around the index that you get the invalid start byte: is there text that looks "wrong"?

Comment: ISO-8859-1 doesn't have a character at 0x80. Did you try Windows-1252 or other Windows codepages, depending on language of the data

Comment: "The file may contain characters from different encodings"  -> this is a situation you want to avoid if at all possible.

Comment: We can't tell you the correct encoding without seeing (a representative, ideally small sample of) the actual data in an unambiguous representation; a hex dump of the problematic byte(s) with a few bytes of context on each side is often enough, especially if you can tell us what you think those bytes are supposed to represent. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can handle this in Python and it depends on **what you** want to happen. Here are examples.

data.txt (UTF-16 LE)

```
Hellö, Wörld!
```

1. *Strict try/except*: You could simply not read a file unless it uses a valid utf-8 encoding.

   ```py
   from pathlib import Path

   try:
       with Path.open("data.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f:
           content = f.read()
   except UnicodeDecodeError:
       print("The file couldn't be read, it's not valid utf-8.")
   else:
       print(content)

   # The file couldn't be read, it's not valid utf-8.
   ```
2. [*Handle decoding errors*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers): `open()` has a parameter called `errors` in which you define how an error should be handled, by default is `strict` which is why you get a `UnicodeDecodeError` exception. If you use `ignore` it will simply omit the character without raising an exception.

   ```py
   from pathlib import Path

   try:
       with Path.open("data.txt", encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore") as f:
           content = f.read()
   except UnicodeDecodeError:
       print("The file couldn't be read, it's not valid utf-8.")
   else:
       print(content)

   # Hell, Wrld!
   ```
3. Use a module (*[charset_normalizer](https://github.com/Ousret/charset_normalizer#charset-detection-for-everyone-)*) **this option is [not always realiable](https://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#what-is-character-encoding-auto-detection)**

   > A library that helps you read text from an unknown charset encoding.

   ```py
   from charset_normalizer import from_path

   print(str(from_path("data.txt").best()))

   # Hellö, Wörld!
   ```

You should assume and expect files with utf-8 encoding. [Most websites use](https://w3techs.com/technologies/cross/character_encoding/ranking) utf-8.